# How to set print and save as pdf icon in TYPO3 pages

Tags: typo3

Can anybody help me that how can i set PRINT and save as PDF icon(functionality) in TYPO3 pages ?

Thanks...in advance..

Comment: You need at least tell us how have you built your templates.

Comment: hi.. i am using default template of typo3. (Introduction template)

Comment: Hi marcus, can you please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many examples in Google and I think that you should browse them, to find the one the best fits your needs.

In general 'historically' print version was suggested to be build with new `PAGE` cObject which `typeNum` is set to `98` (of course that's only suggestion) in general going this clue, you should find many examples and other resources by searching in Google for `typo3 typeNum 98`.

When you'll create alternative `PAGE` object (and maybe also use modified template for it) you need also add on your webpage a link which be the same as the current URL but with additional param `&type=98`, when user will click it TYPO3 will open the alternative version of the page. So you can add to this a JS in header which will also start system's print dialog.

You can also search the [extensions repository](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository) and find something for placing the print button if you are unfamiliar with `TypoScript`.

PDF rendering is similar from point of view of the frontend, however most probably you need to  use some additional lib, so it will be best to search for [ready to use solution from the repo](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/?id=23&L=0&q=pdf).

In general PDF version could be tricky,  therefore from my experience I can say that nowadays it's sometimes better to avoid the PDF icon at all or use linking to some external service. Of course all depends on your needs. Remember that there are many programs which are able to create PDF's so if it is not required maybe it's no worth of its effort.

Finally take a look at the [AddThis](http://www.addthis.com/) widget it can be also used for easy adding of icons for printing and online PDF creation, additionally you can also send invitations via e-mail, or even share the link on the hundreds social portals. And what's most important installing this is just like adding view lines of HTML code vie TypoScript.

Comment: hi marcus.. thanks for your great explanation. i am looking it..